# jQuery Image Mask

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-plugins

Does anyone know of a jQuery control that allows me to say have an image that represents a page where there is a one or more say Blue boxes on it representing where images will go on that page.

Then I would like to drag and drop images onto the blue areas only without the need to map them first.

I think this is called masking where by i can represent a page as an image and designate certain areas as a color and those areas are then drop areas for say photos.

Really sorry if this is unclear and I will attempt to change if anyone can suggest alterations.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understand, but it remains me [one of my project](http://www.cutmyface.com), where i was playing with the draggable feature of jquery, in order to define a crop for a picture in order to design fancy facebook profile.

You can have a look to the facebook application, it is still working great ;)

The [link to the JQuery interaction page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)

Comment: Not really no.  What I guess I'm looking for is what is called chromakeying in video editing I think.  So you have a blue screen and you can overlay that with what ever.  In my case there might be two "blue" areas that the plugin needs to see and turn into droppable areas.